# Vb.net picturebox zooming

Tags: vb.net, mouse, picturebox, zooming

I am attempting to replicate windows photo viewer, to an extent.

Right now I have a form with a picturebox, and the ability to move it around with the mouse and zoom in/out with the scroll wheel.

However, I wish to zoom towards the mouse pointer. You can see what I am trying to explain by opening a decently big image in windows photo viewer, and zooming with your mouse somewhere away from the center of the image. I want to replicate that, but so far I can only zoom in and out.

I know that I have to move the image in the opposite direction of the mouse pointer to the center of the form, and vary how much it moves per scroll wheel tick depending on how far your mouse is from the center of the form, but this is where I'm stuck.

Here's my laughable, confused piece of code that's half commented out and partway between not working and completely not working:

```
    Dim Me_Center As Point = New Point(Me.Width / 2, Me.Height / 2)
    Dim PB_Center_R As Point = New Point(PictureBox1.Width / 2, PictureBox1.Height / 2)
    Dim PB_Center As Point = New Point(PictureBox1.Location.X + PB_Center_R.X, PictureBox1.Location.Y + PB_Center_R.Y)
    Dim PB_Diff As Point = (PB_Center - MousePos)


    PictureBox1.Location = New Point((Me_Center - PB_Center_R) - PB_Diff)

    'PictureBox1.Location = New Point((Me.Width / 2) - (PictureBox1.Width / 2), (Me.Height / 2) - (PictureBox1.Height / 2))

    '(Me.Width / 2) - (PictureBox1.Width + Pos.X / 2), (Me.Height / 2) - (PictureBox1.Height - Pos.Y / 2)
    'PictureBox1.Location = New Point((Me.Width / 2 - (PictureBox1.Width / 2)) + XP, (Me.Height / 2 - (PictureBox1.Height / 2)) - YP)
```

this does pretty much exactly what I want (if you hit the "Open Zoomable Image" when running this form, however I can't understand exactly how it works: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?654846-ZoomPictureBox-picture-control-with-mouse-centred-zooming

Comment: What have you researched? What code have you tried? We don't build software for people.

Comment: Well, I've found absolutely nothing on this particular thing, except this: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?654846-ZoomPictureBox-picture-control-with-mouse-centred-zooming

Unfortunately I can't understand what's going on with this exactly enough to adapt it.

I understand you guys don't, and very much shouldn't just hand out code. I only ask this question because of my lack of results in my research, and my broken code. I've written and re-written a section of code that's supposed to work a few times, and right now I have nothing but pieces to show for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the PictureBox that contains the image the way you want. Set the SizeMode to `Zoom` so the image readjust its size automatically:

```
PictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
```

And then resize the PictureBox as you want.

You can detect the mouse position in the form by adding the event MouseMove on the form and storing the position in a variable. Or you can get the mouse position in the screen at any moment with:

```
Dim p As Point = Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
```

You can read a similar question here: [How to zoom in a Picturebox with scrollwheel in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496706/how-to-zoom-in-a-picturebox-with-scrollwheel-in-vb-net)

Comment: Let me clarify a bit, I've already got zooming working and down just as it should function. However, what I want to do is zoom towards the mouse's position on the form, exactly as windows photo viewer does. I've tried to do this for quite a while, with no luck, I'm not just starting out on this. I ask for help continuing this to get it working, not to start this.

Comment: Then you should make better questions. Better questions give better answers. If you don't clarify what you want is difficult to us to help in your specific problem. Anyway, you can resize the Picturebox according to the mouse position, for example, if cursor is on the right position of the image, then resize the image to the left.

Comment: I realize this, I remade the OP to be more clear.

What you say about resizing the picture box opposite the mouse position, I know that. I just don't know how I can go about that correctly.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm looking for the same thing.